# How to further filter Page Leadgen Forms in FB API to just get active forms

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the list of active leadgen forms. To do so I am using the following path in the graph API explorer.

```
<page_id>?fields=leadgen_forms{name,leads{field_data},leads_count,created_time,status}&filtering=[{field: 'status',operator: 'EQUAL', value: 'ACTIVE'}]
```

and still returns all lead forms.

I also tried

```
<page_id>?fields=leadgen_forms{name,leads{field_data},leads_count,created_time,status}&filtering=[{field: 'leadgen_forms.status',operator: 'EQUAL', value: 'ACTIVE'}]
```

and still the same result.

Does anyone know how to filter down the data?

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know how to make it work through that endpoint but I just found out that there is another endpoint and this time it worked as expected so instead of getting `leadgen_form` as a field and did it as an endpoint. I think that is why it did not work before.

```
<page_id>/leadgen_forms

fields=created_time,name,status,locale,expired_leads_count,leads_count,organic_leads_count,page,leads&limit=2&filtering=[{field: 'status',operator: 'EQUAL', value: 'ARCHIVED'}]
```